# Why does NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle default to US on A British Mac in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

Why does the following code print the value in dollars on a British Mac in the iOS simulator and what can I do about it without hard coding a £ ?

```
class func currencyStringFromNumber(number:Double) -> String {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter();
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle;
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(number) ?? "";
}
```

Would the above 'just work' on a real device or do I need to add further checks in a real world app?

I'd like the values to display in British pounds on my own computer in the iOS simulator by detecting the locale automatically. I realise I can do:

```
    let blightyLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB");
    formatter.locale = blightyLocale;
```

Comment: have you actually gone into the settings in the simulator and checked the region settings? its probably US by default

Comment: no! d'oh. I had forgotten all about the settings app on the Simulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like a mobile device each simulator has its own settings.
The default locale on the simulator is `en_US`

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that the Simulator has its own settings App, just like a real device. [image]